# Symfony2 QueryBuilder not working

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am learning Symfony2 with Doctrine2

I am trying to use `createQueryBuilder()`, but I get an error when I try to call the results in my `indexController`.

The Error is:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class API\TestBundle\TestDoctrine\Repository\TestRepo could not be converted to string in /Users/tomasz.koprowski/Dev/jv-api/src/API/TestBundle/Controller/IndexController.php on line 60
```

My TestRepo:

```
<?php

namespace API\TestBundle\TestDoctrine\Repository;

use API\TestBundle\TestDoctrine\DatabaseRepository;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;


class TestRepo extends DatabaseRepository{

    protected $test = array();

    public function __construct(
        Connection $connection,
        LoggerInterface $logger
    ){
        parent::__construct($connection, $logger);
    }

    public function getTestData()
    {

        $check = $this->db->createQueryBuilder()

            ->select('test.user_name')
            ->from('test');

        $this->test = $check->execute()->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $this->test;
    }
}
```

My Controller:

```
<?php
namespace API\TestBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

use API\TestBundle\TestDoctrine\Repository\TestRepo;

class IndexController
{
    public $test;

    public function __construct(
        TestRepo $test
    ) {
        $this->$test = $test;
    }

    public function testDoctrineAction()
    {
       return new JsonResponse($this->test->getTestData());
    }
}
```

Any Idea where I am going wrong with this one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here :

`$this->$test = $test;`

You can probably figure out yourself what is going wrong : ) And i'm pretty sure this is line 60, as said in the error message.

I'm not giving you the answer because this is typically a kind of error your should spot by yourself before asking on StackOverflow. If you can figure it yourself, you probably won't make it again.

Comment: ok i can see it now...... everyone can make a silly mistake thx for pointing it out dough :)